# bash: passing multiple arguments into a command programatically

Tags: bash, shell, pandoc

I want to run a `pandoc` command (creates `pdf` file from one or more `.md`) files passed as input arguments.

However, the list of `.md` files is not known a priori.

I want to run sth like

```
pandoc -s -o out.pdf file1.md ... fileN.md
```

I can retrieve the `md` files via `find`, i.e.

```
find . -name '*.md'
```

and then run an exec, i.e.

```
find . -name '*.md' -exec bash -c 'pandoc -s -o out.pdf $0 -' {} \;
```

but this will call `pandoc` iteratively and not in one go with all the `.md` files.

Comment: Do you habe subdirs or why not use plain shell expansion?

Comment: `.md` files are scattered in subdirectories

Comment: Then use your find approach combined with xargs.

Comment: `xargs` works iteratively as `exec`, no?

Comment: No, xargs will aggregate all filenames and run only one pandoc process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bash` glob options to do this trick. Set all the `.md` files in the array and pass it to the command in one shot.

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
file_list=( **/file*.md )
```

Now that the array is populated, pass it to the command as needed

```
pandoc -s -o out.pdf "${file_list[@]}"
```

Before passing it to the command, you can use `printf` to see if the array contains all the files as needed

```
printf '%s' "${file_list[@]}"
```

The `nullglob` option is to prevent the expansion from returning a plain string if there are no files matching the `file*.md` glob pattern. The `globstar` option will glob the files in any levels of sub-directories below.

Also as one step safety way you can do it as below to ensure running the command if the array count is non-zero

```
(( "${#file_list[@]}" )) && pandoc -s -o out.pdf "${file_list[@]}"
```

Also it would be a safe practice to disable the glob action once you no longer need it using the unset (`-u`) flag.

```
shopt -u nullglob globstar
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, although I am having some `pandoc` specific issues :)

Comment: what kind of string will the expansion return if we do not set the `nullglob` option? something like `null` for example?

Comment: @pkaramol: It will store `**/file*.md` as a _literal_ string in the array without expanding it

Answer (score 1):

Do not have pandoc here, but something like this should work:

```
find . -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 pandoc -s -o out.pdf
```

Comment: It would be nice if someone could elaborate on the pros/cons (if any) of the two proposed solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do files+=("$REPLY"); done < <(find . -name "*.md" -print0) && pandoc -s -o out.pdf "${files[@]}"
```

Make a while loop for pass files to files array and after run pandoc